# Анимация uibutton при свайпе таблицы

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile

Как реализовать плавную анимацию uibutton, которая находится поверх таблицы, чтоб при промотке вниз таблицы кнопка исчезала плавно, вверх появлялась, как в "Вконтакте" в ленте новостей кнопка внизу синяя "записи"? Если через scrollviewdidscroll просто указывая хиден, то кнопка резко исчезает, а надо красиво, плавно.

```
@IBOutlet weak var startWorkoutButton: UIButton!

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {  //резко исчезает
        startWorkoutButton.hidden = true
    } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 { //резко появляется
        startWorkoutButton.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнопка это потомок `UIView`, так что если посмотреть документацию от Apple то можно найти вот это [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108)

Ну а там вы найдете методы анимации `Animating Views with Block Objects`

В вашем случае используйте изменение свойства `alpha` у кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var startWorkoutButton: UIButton!

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        UIButton.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.startWorkoutButton.alpha = 0.0
            self.startWorkoutButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 600)
            })
    } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        UIButton.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.startWorkoutButton.alpha = 1.0
            self.startWorkoutButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
        })
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    startWorkoutButton.alpha = 1.0
    startWorkoutButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
}
```

Спасибо. Мне нравится такой вариант...